# URL Encryption in php when passing sensitive parameters (joomla+codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, iframe, encryption

I'm using codeigniter inside joomla by using iframe.
Some pages i need to get the user group if admin or user 
So i find a way to send values to iframe by using url with the following code:

```
<?php
//add user id
$user_id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
?>

<iframe <?php echo $this->wrapper->load; ?>
   id="blockrandom"
   name="iframe"
   src="<?php echo $this->escape($this->wrapper->url) . "?user=" . $user_id; ?>"
```

The problem is the type of the user will apear in url so is their any way to encrype the url and decrypt it in the other page?

Comment: sure. a very simple not-encryption-but-just-for-example would be `src=<?php echo base64_encode($this->escape(...))`, then `base64_decode()` in the receiving script.

Comment: Can anyone hack it by your way?

Comment: sure. if you use a cereal box encoder for encryption, then anyone can hack it. appropriate choice and use of the encryption function is up to you.

Comment: Is their any other way more secure?

Comment: sure, don't round-trip secure data through the client. store the data in a server-side session so the user never has a chance to see it.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> is their any way to encrype the url and decrypt it in the other page?

You're asking for some way to do this...

[image: Encrypt a URL parameter]

...when in reality, you want to do *this*:

[image: Use a random lookup instead]

The reasons why you want to avoid encryption are explained in depth [in this blog post](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php), but the main reasons are that encrypting URL parameters introduces the following concerns to your application:

1. Chosen-ciphertext attacks
2. Replay attacks
3. Secure encryption would result URLs longer than most people are happy with (IV/nonce + HMAC tag)
4. Side-channel cryptanalysis

Whereas the alternative is: You can simply add a `UNIQUE TEXT` field to your SQL table, populate it with `base64_encode(random_bytes(15))`, and call it a day.

All together now, shouting from the rooftops: **Don't encrypt URL parameters, use a randomized lookup instead.**